# Ajax call inside webpage repeated on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arduino, esp8266

I'm running a server, serving a simple webpage. The page has buttons forming a keypad that make simple Ajax calls to the server, like this:

```
 <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('button_1')">
    1
 </button>
```

The makeAjaxCall function is very simple, too:

```
function makeAjaxCall(url){$.ajax({"url":url})}
```

The server listens for this, and does something, like this:

```
server.on("/button_1", [](){
   Serial.println("User has entered 1");
   server.send(200, "text/plain", "User has entered 0");
});
```

(FWIW, the server is running on ESP8266, Written using Arduino IDE.)

What I've noticed is that sometimes, when I refresh the page manually, the last Ajax call, or last several Ajax calls, are repeated. So I push 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and then refresh, the page will refresh, but all those calls will be made again. This seems to happen somewhat sporadically and unpredictably. Also, if multiple calls are repeated, they can get scrambled around. And if the phenomenon happens on one refresh, and I refresh again without making any new Ajax calls, then the phenomenon repeats (though the calls might be scrambled around yet again).

So a typical serial output might look like this:

```
User has entered 1  //Manually entered in browser on page
User has entered 2  //Manually entered in browser on page
User has entered 3  //Manually entered in browser on page
Refresh page        //Refresh in browser
User has entered 2  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
User has entered 3  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
User has entered 1  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
Refresh page        //Refresh in browser
User has entered 1  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
User has entered 2  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
User has entered 3  //Appears on its own at time of refresh
```

Note that the erroneous calls don't come in the same order after the two refreshes. Again, this doesn't happen after every refresh.

Is there something about Ajax that could explain this? Could it be a browser issue? (I'm testing this in iOS Safari and macOS Safari.)

If I make these calls and then wait, where could they even be stored for this to happen? Something must remember to repeat them. Would it be the server? Would it be the browser?

Could it be a hardware issue? (Might the board itself keep this in some buffer somewhere? That's a little out of my league.)

EDIT: Adding full HTML, in case it helps:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Garage Door Opener</title>
    <meta charset="utf-16">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <style>
      body,button {
        touch-action:manipulation;
        background-color:#282828;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:'Avenir Medium';
      }
      .container {
        text-align:center;
        height:100%;
        width:56.2vh;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:none;
      }
      .row {
        z-index:5;
        height:12vh;
        width:100%;
        display:table;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding-bottom: 6vh;
      }
      .cell{
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin:auto;
      }
      .bottom {
        vertical-align:bottom;
      }
      .top {
        vertical-align:top;
      }
      .special-mid {
        width:14vh;
      }
      .special-side {
        width:21.1vh;
      }
      .left {
        text-align:left;
      }
      .right {
        text-align:right;
      }
      .half{
        width:50%;
      }
      .third{
        width:33%;
      }
      .wide{
        width:100%;
      }
      .fourth{
        width:25%;
      }
      .fifth{
        width:20%;
      }
      .push {
        border:0;
        border-radius:70%;
        height:11.2vh;
        width:11.2vh;
        margin:auto;
      }
      .display {
        border:0;
        border-radius:0;
        height:11.2vh;
        width:90%;
        margin:auto;
      }
      .red {
        color:white;
        background-color:red;
      }
      .green {
        color:white;
        background-color:green;
      }
      .purple {
        color:white;
        background-color:purple;
      }
      .orange {
        color:white;
        background-color:#FFA500;
      }
      .blue {
        color:white;
        background-color:#1E90FF;
      }
      .white {
        color:#282828;
        background-color:white;
      }
      .white-outline {
        color:white;
        border:0.5vh solid;
        border-color:white;
        background-color:#282828;
      }
      .white-outline:active {
        color:#282828;
        border:0.5vh solid;
        border-color:white;
        background-color:white;
      }
      .green-outline {
        color:lime;
        border:0.5vh solid;
        border-color:lime;
        background-color:#282828;
      }
      .yellow-outline {
        color:yellow;
        border:0.5vh solid;
        border-color:yellow;
        background-color:#282828;
      }
      .red-outline {
        color:red;
        border:0.5vh solid;
        border-color:red;
        background-color:#282828;
      }
      .none {
        color:#282828;
        background-color:#282828;
      }
      .material-icons.md-18 {
        font-size:3.75vh;
        line-height:6.56vh;
        letter-spacing:-2.4vh;
      }
      .text-entry {
        font-size:3.75vh;
        line-height:1.875vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script> function makeAjaxCall(url){$.ajax({"url":url})}</script>
  <body ontouchstart="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell wide">
          <button class="display white">
            Garage status:
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_1')">
            <p class="text-entry">1</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_2')">
            <p class="text-entry">2</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_3')">
            <p class="text-entry">3</p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_4')">
            <p class="text-entry">4</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_5')">
            <p class="text-entry">5</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_6')">
            <p class="text-entry">6</p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_7')">
            <p class="text-entry">7</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_8')">
            <p class="text-entry">8</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_9')">
            <p class="text-entry">9</p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell third">
            <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/del_char')">
              <i class="material-icons md-18">backspace</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/add_0')">
            <p class="text-entry">0</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cell third">
          <button class="push white-outline" onclick="makeAjaxCall('/reset')">
            <i class="material-icons md-18">cancel</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script> function makeAjaxCall(url){$.ajax({"url":url})}</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your `makeAjaxCall()` code?

Comment: Oops, oops, oops. Edited to include this. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding a `/` to your request? `onclick="makeAjaxCall('/button_1')"`. This could solve the issue.

Comment: @AlainCruz I believe  he is showing pseudo code for his `makeAjaxCall()` function.  It wouldn't hit the server at all with that response if the URL were wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I never thought of that. The code executes fine without it, and the server responds as I would want it. Is it possible for this to happen but still cause the strange erroneous behavior? I didn’t think to check what adding the / does.

Comment: I suspect there is something else happening in your HTML.  You should post the entire HTML which correctly reproduces the issue instead of snippets of pseudo code, please.

Comment: @magneticmagnum Sure, thanks, I've posted the full HTML! (Apologies for the CSS…)

Comment: @AlainCruz Oh, and oops! You're absolutely right about the /. I guess I *do* have it in the code above. Apologies about that!

Comment: Could you open the `Network` tab in your browser and see if any requests are getting sent on page refresh?

Comment: Is it a mistake that you duplicated the `script` or is that how it is right now? This could definitely cause issues.

Comment: @magneticmagnum I will try to do this ASAP. Thanks for your interest. I'm at work, but will try to get to it ASAP.

Comment: @AlainCruz Thanks for noticing that. That's a mistake, but the issue persists without it, sadly. :(

Comment: Clear your browsing history and cache. If you had opened http://example.com/add_1 in your address bar, your browser might have started hitting those urls in background for some analysis purpose. This is an artificial intelligence feature in safari.